# Drag & drop item from one timeline calendar to other react

Tags: reactjs, calendar, drag-and-drop

I am using [react-calendar-timeline](https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline) for my project. I have requirements where i need to drag and drop item(s) from one calendar to other. Currently react-calendar-timeline library doesn't support such a thing from my findings.

Question is how can i drag and drop item(s) between calendars using react-calendar-timeline library? I am pretty sure it's doable but can't find out myself.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone guide me or provide me a hint.

Thanks

Comment: suggest you just ask this in their repo. this is too specfic of a question and isnt a react question

Comment: what do you mean by _between calendars_ ? Do you want to move around the blue items in [this link](https://namespace-ee.github.io/react-calendar-timeline-docs/#/main), between days and months ??

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is irrelevant ( or almost impossible ). Looking at the demo of `react-calendar-timeline` [here](https://namespace-ee.github.io/react-calendar-timeline-docs/#/main), the only component being rendered is the `<Timeline>` component, and all items are being passed to it using `items` prop. That being the case, you can implement drag-and-drop only using any of the following ways:

1. **Fork your own copy** of `react-calendar-timeline` and implement draggability of items between calendars. It's not that difficult a task as it may seem, as the library is designed in a [component based manner](https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline/blob/master/src/lib/items/Item.js). Actually, digging further, I found [this thread](https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline/issues/156) on that repo, in which one of the participants had [forked and implemented drag and drop](https://github.com/foufee/react-calendar-timeline) in his/her version. So you might draw inspiration from there :)
2. **Use any other library** like jQuery or D3 to implement drag and drop feature to individual elements by inspecting and selecting them via selectors. **This is not at all recommended** , as manipulating the DOM directly eliminates the whole point of using React, and it may interfere seriously with React's algorithms.

So that's it. Basically, as the library doesn't support the feature, you can't have the feature out of the box :)